# Why doesn't soup.select('.r a') find anything in my google search?

Tags: python

I'm trying out the lucky.py project in this book, https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/. The program runs fine, but I can't get beautifulsoup to select the correct links.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried soup.select('div') and it chooses all the links from the top.

Tried soup.select('span div') and it selects all the sublinks on each search result.

Looked up lots over questions, but none of them seems to answer why soup.select('.r a') doesn't work or how to fix it.

When I enter print(linkElems) in the code, it shows me an empty dictionary.

**This is my code:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4

print('Googling...')    # display text while downloading the Google page

res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")

linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('https://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

I'm expecting it to open the first 5 links of the google search in new tabs, but nothing comes up because the selector isn't working properly.

Comment: I think you should dump the downloaded HTML to a file and view it locally. I imagine that the google search page looks a bit different when downloaded vs when you do it in a browser. This is because I believe google does some javascript changes on it altering classes and such. In short, the selector is working fine, there is just no class `.r` when you evaluate it in your script.

Comment: Hey facelessuser, I tried it, but it threw off some weird results. It opened the main google page, the first result, the 2nd and 3rd results without loading properly, and another blank google homepage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like class r (.r) means tag for one link.
If class r has only one a tag, multiple links can't be opened.

So, you might need to search upper tag like "div tag + id='search'", for example, div#search

Then, returned object will contain all a tags because element of "div#search" is located upper than all a tags

Comment: I actually did try div#search, but it also returned nothing for some reason. I can see the div class=search in the html inspector, so I'm a bit confused why it doesn't work

Comment: @nicklin I generally use Selenium than BeautifulSoup when crawling web data. I assume Google search is done without JavaScript but if Google search uses JavaScript (randering result in real time, so they can't be catched by BeatifulSoup), you can be needed to use Selenium in that situation. And another tip is to check "text" in the tag, for example, by using element.text. And try to search how many tags are there by typing the tag name after pressing CTRL+F in dev tool mode in Chrome